# Message box to verify a file has been copied from executable to temp directory

Tags: c#, installshield

I need to create a message box that verifies the response.ini file is copied from the Setup.exe installer to the local temp folder on the host box.

This is a small part of a larger installshield executable file. The installer keeps failing and saying no Response.ini file is found. I need to verify that the Reponse.ini file is actually being copied over to the "Temp" folder the installer is looking for. I am trying to add a Message box during the installer to verify the file has been copied over.

below is the code. I would like to add a message box after to verify.

```
szProgram = szSource ^ "SETUP.EXE";
if Is(FILE_EXISTS, szProgram) then
    //Copy Response.INI file to local drive and set it to be rewritable. 
    XCopyFile(SUPPORTDIR ^ "Response.INI", "C:\\TEMP\\" COMP_NORMAL);
    szINIFile = "C:" ^ "Temp" ^ "Response.ini";
    SetFileInfo(szINIFile, FILE_ATTRIBUTE, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, "");
```

Comment: Are you sure the response.ini file is unpacked from the setup when doing this operation?